# Is std::type_index unique?

Tags: c++, std, typeid

I hope to use `std::map` to store information for different datatype by `type_index`, learned from cppreference.com.

For example:

```cpp
#include <typeindex>
class A{};
class B{};
int main()
{
    map<type_index, string> info{
        {type_index[typeid(A)], "Information for class A."},
        {type_index[typeid(B)], "Information for class B."}
    };
}
```

`typeid()` will return a struct `type_info`.

But I learnt that `type_info.hash_code()` may be not unique.Different type may have same `hash_code`.
I wonder if `type_index` is unique ?

Comment: your code does not compile, not only due to missing includes, but I think you misunderstood the example. `type_index[ ... ]` is wrong

Comment: In general, hashes are never guaranteed to be unique.  (There are some special cases which can guarantee the hash is unique, but those really are special cases.)  However, it is extremely unlikely that a `type_info.hash_code()` will collide.

Comment: Yes, use as map keys [is exactly what `type_index` was designed for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index).

Comment: This is the nature of hashed - the do not provide such warranty. They are just use to quickly filter/find items which can be equal.

Comment: The hash code isn't used by `std::map` in the first place. If you used `std::unordered_map`, the hash code would be used to find a bucket, and then the (unambiguous) equality operator would be used to identify the correct element. That's how hash maps work, and how hash codes are intended to be used. Collision is not a problem.

Comment: @Eljay Well, accidental collisions of `type_info.hash_code()` may be rare but it's trivial to make type names that, in common implementations, cause collisions on purpose. Non-collision is not a property that can be relied on for correctness (unlike what cryptographic hashes such as SHA-256 provide).

Comment: From the specification of `type_index`, two instances only compare equal to each other if the corresponding `type_info` objects refer to the same type (no ifs, no buts)  - unlike the specification of the `.hash_code()`.  That suggests they are "unique"   (albeit the *ordering* of `type_index` objects, as defined by `operator<()`, etc, is implementation-defined).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `std::type_index` is unique. It's said to work [as if it held a pointer to `std::type_info`](http://eel.is/c++draft/type.index#overview).

Even though [you can get different pointers for the same type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid#Notes), they're not compared directly. Rather, [`std::type_info::before()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/before) is used.